# PHP foreach while loop how to sum output

Tags: php, checkbox, foreach, while-loop, sum

Query returns sum of elements group by operator (selected by checkbox).

How to sum up all that values? I tried using array_sum() but didn't worked or maybe i am not using this function correct.
Thank you

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
$ziua=$_POST["date"];
}
else 
{
    $ziua=date('Y-m-d');
}
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{//check to see if the delete button has been pressed
    if(isset($_POST['box']))
    { //check to see if any boxes have been checked 
        $num = 0;//used to count the number of rows that were deleted
        $box = $_POST['box'];
        foreach ($box as $key =>$val) 
        { //loop through all the checkboxes
                  $num++;

              $sqldel=" SELECT U.username , SUM(L.geometrie1) A from list L,users U where L.user_id='$val' 
              and L.date_posted like '%$ziua%' AND L.user_id=U.id group by U.username  ";//delete any that match id
              $resdel=mysql_query($sqldel);//send the query to mysql

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resdel))
            {
            Print "<tr>";
            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['0']. "</td>";
            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['1']. "</td>";
            Print "</tr>";
            }
         }
    }
}
?>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: result is something like: admin -> 5, user 8 and i want to be like admin -> 5, user 8,  total-> 13

Comment: As always: ***please*** stop using the ***deprecated*** `mysql` extension. [read ***the red warning*** box](http://php.net/mysql_connect): The extension is no longer maintained, and will be removed in the future. Learn to use `PDO` or `mysqli` (the `i` is for _improved_). Also learn about prepared statements, while you're at it. `PDO` is more commonly used (as its API is a lot nicer). `mysqli` offers a procedural API _and_ an OO one, but is a lot messier. They both have their stronger and weaker points, so play around with both, see which one you prefer

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Please post Full Code. I'm not seeing any where you are adding

Comment: @NanaPartykar: That's why he posted the question in the first place: OP isn't adding anything in the loop, that's the problem :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you loop add

```
 $total=0;
```

In your loop add

```
  $total += $row[1];
```

Then echo it after the loop

Comment: i did result is : 58 and that is my problem for last 4 days. it returns result  as an array.

Comment: $total=0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resdel))
    {
      

    Print "<tr>";
     

      Print '<td align="center">'. $row['0']. "</td>";
      Print '<td align="center">'. $row['1']. "</td>";
      $total += $row[1];
     Print "</tr>";
  echo $total;
    }

Comment: Nope that is not what i said. Echo your total **after** your loop, not inside it.

Comment: foreach ($box as $key =>$val) { 
              $num++;
           
         $sqldel=" SELECT U.username , SUM(L.geometrie1) A from list L,users U where L.user_id='$val' 
      and L.date_posted like '%$ziua%' AND L.user_id=U.id group by U.username  ";
              $resdel=mysql_query($sqldel);
    
 $total=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resdel))
    {

    Print "<tr>";
     
      Print '<td align="center">'. $row['0']. "</td>";
      Print '<td align="center">'. $row['1']. "</td>";
      $total += $row[1];
     Print "</tr>";
  
    }
  

  }
  echo $total;
}

   }

Comment: returns only 8  sum for the last operator i select

Comment: Remove total=0 before the second loop, place it even before the first loop thats common mathematics

Comment: is my first script i'm trying to write. and first time on this site :)